# Creating my own Text Categorizer - How to create a new column that checks if Key in Text and return Group across multiple rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a new column that reflects the Group of the Text based on whether the Text contains keywords

The code for creating the data and expected output is as below. I know of functions that can compare across the same row but not across multiple roles as this one requires.

Creating a dictionary was one approach I tried, but it would be a massive dictionary beyond these test cases

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Group': ['Greetings', 'Farewells', 'Requests'], 'Key':['Hello hey','Goodbye', 'I need help'], 
       'Text': ['Hey Bob, goodbye', 'Hey, have you met handsome Terence?', 'Hey Omg I really need help']}

data2 = {'Group': ['Greetings', 'Farewells', 'Requests'], 'Key':['Hello hey','Goodbye', 'I need help'], 
       'Text': ['Hey Bob, goodbye', 'Hey, have you met handsome Terence?', 'Hey Omg I really need help'], 
         'Groupings': ['Greetings, Farewells', 'Greetings', 'Greetings, Requests']}


new_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(new_df)

expected_output = pd.DataFrame(data2)

expected_output
```

Text 1 has groupings Greetings, Farewells because it contains keywords "Hey" and "Goodbye".

Text 3 has groupings Greetings, Requests because it contains keywords "Hey" and "I need help" is found within the Text

Hope I've provided enough information to go on

EDIT: Also as a side-question, how do I include the tables in the question to make it easier to view?